# Converting date format in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, format, date-conversion

I have a date format in the form dd.mm.yyyy I want to convert it mm/dd/yyyy. Is it possible?

All the articles on the internet I read had dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy was possible and it worked when I tried.

But when I put dd.mm.yyyy it does not work? How can I fix it?

Please help me

Comment: Are you working with a "date" column or a "varchar2" with formatted text? An actual date column can be formatted on select to display as whatever format you want with to_char. Use to_date to format text as a date data type if you are inserting or updating.

Comment: What is doing the displaying? The storage format and the display format are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle stores dates using an internal format.  If you have a *string* that represents a date, you should probably fix your data model, so the column has the correct data type.

In the meantime, you can convert it to a `date` using:

```
select to_date(col, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

You can convert this back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date(col, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks alot. If I want to include the time format like the following how is it possible?                                                                                                       select to_char(to_date('16.12.2020 10:10:20 PM', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual. This gave an error

Comment: You would include the time format elements in `to_date()`/`to_char()`.  These are well documented.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a date format in the form dd.mm.yyyy

Assuming that you mean a `DATE` data type then, no, you don't have it in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`. A `DATE` data type value is stored within the database as a binary value in 7-bytes (representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second) and this has no format.

> I want to convert it mm/dd/yyyy. Is it possible?

No, because `DATE` data types do not have a format.

However, what you probably meant to ask is:

> I want to <s>convert</s> display as it mm/dd/yyyy. Is it possible?

Yes, use `TO_CHAR` with the appropriate [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-FC63D86D-EB36-4A19-995E-C3C146747DF4):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( date_value, 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
FROM   table_name
```

---

If you mean that you have a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` data type storing date values in the format `dd.mm.yyyy` then use `TO_DATE` to convert it to a `DATE` data type and then `TO_CHAR` to display it to the format you want.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( string_value, 'dd.mm.yyyy' ), 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
FROM   table_name
```